# Kotlin property initialization

Tags: kotlin

I've created the following snippet, not anything that I would actually write in production, but just to help me understand how properties are initialized:

```
class C {
    val a: String = run {
        println("init a")
        f()
    }
    val b: String = run {
        println("init b: a=$a")
        a
    }

    private fun f(): String {
        println("f(): a=$a, b=$b")
        return b
    }
}

fun main() {
    println(C().a)
    println(C().b)
}
```

Note that all properties are `val` and `String`, so immutable and non-nullable. Yet the output shows that they are `null`.

Is the result of this code well-defined? Is there somewhere in the language spec that says that a non-nullable property can in fact be null when you access it from the wrong place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [Kotlin/Core spec](https://kotlinlang.org/spec/declarations.html#classifier-initialization), the order of the execution is specified,

> When a classifier type is initialized using a particular secondary constructor ctor delegated to primary constructor pctor which, in turn, is delegated to the corresponding superclass constructor sctor , the following happens, in this initialization order:
>
> - [...]
> - Each property initialization code as well as the initialization blocks in the class body are invoked in the order of appearance in the
>   class body;
> - [...]

but the values of the uninitialised properties are not.

> If any of the properties are accessed before they are initialized w.r.t initialization order (e.g., if a method called in an initialization block accesses a property declared after the initialization block), the value of the property is unspecified. It stays unspecified even after the “proper” initialization is performed.

In other words, you will see the messages printed in the order of

```
init a
f(): a=null, b=null
init b: a=null
null
```

but the values are not guaranteed to be null.

There might be stronger guarantees in Kotlin/JVM, but there is no spec for that right now.

Comment: Very nice.  So a `run` block is basically equivalent to calling a method on the object when used in the same way to initialize a property by referring to another yet-to-be-initialized property.

Answer (score 0):

This is explicitly not an answer, just two small remarks/questions:

First, doesn't one of the three members a, b, or f() need to be set to a or return a value? The way it is in the OPs code, everything is null by definition as there is no non-null value anywhere. The 'call chain' is a –> f() –> b, so if we set b to a value like "start", it would look like this:

```
class C {
  val a: String = run { f() }
  val b: String = run { "start" }
  private fun f(): String = b
}

fun main() {
  val c = C()
  println(c.a)   // Output: null
  println(c.b)   // Output: "start"
}
```

Secondly, if the order is changed so that b is appearing in the code before the other two members we get a different result:

```
class C {
  val b: String = run { "start" }
  val a: String = run { f() }
  private fun f(): String = b
}

fun main() {
  val c = C()
  println(c.a)   // Output: "start"
  println(c.b)   // Output: "start"
}
```

Comment: It doesn't matter how the value of `b` is set so long as the code that initializes `a` refers to `b`, and `a` is defined before `b`  in the code. - If you change the order, then yes, the behavior changes, but the whole point of the question is what happens given that `a` is defined before `b`.

Comment: The question was why the output was null while a and b were non-nullable. How would one check that, if there isn't a non-null value assigned somewhere?

Comment: It's not if there is a non-null value or not.  It's why is it possible for a property to end up with a null value, however that happens, given that that should not be possible.